# How to break if field is empty

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtextfield, jpasswordfield

```
   private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String Username=username.getText().toString();
        String PassWord=password.getText().toString();

         if(Username.equals("")){ 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User name is mandatory");
        }
          if(PassWord.equals("")){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password is mandatory");
          }

          }

          addJobOpenning second= new addJobOpenning();
          second.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Which field is empty?

Comment: I want when userName & password fields are not field do not proceed to the next form

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting it completely, from your code i think you need to break if Username or 
PassWord is empty. You can use `return` statement.

```
 private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String Username=username.getText().toString();
        String PassWord=password.getText().toString();

         if(Username.equals("")){ 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User name is mandatory");
             return;
        }
          if(PassWord.equals("")){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password is mandatory");
              return;
          }

          }

          addJobOpenning second= new addJobOpenning();
          second.setVisible(true);
```